# How can I prevent Silverlight from converting TransformGroup to MatrixTransform?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have created a `TransformGroup` with multiple `Transform`s and assigned this to an `Image`'s `RenderTransform` property:

```
TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();

ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
group.Children.Add(st);

TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
group.Children.Add(tt);

image.RenderTransform = group;
```

If I want to get an individual transform from this group in WPF, I can do this:

```
TranslateTransform tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)image.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
```

However, in Silverlight, this `TransformGroup` is apparently implicitly converted to a `MatrixTransform`, because running the above code gives the error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform' to type 'System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup'.

Is there any way to avoid the conversion from `TransformGroup` to `MatrixTransform`? If not, how can I recover the individual `Transform`s from the `MatrixTransform`?

Answer (score 2):

D'oh! I had accidentally tried to use the `TransformGroup` before assigning it, so `image.RenderTransform` was still set to the default of `MatrixTransform`.

In case anyone needed to use a `MatrixTransform` to perform a `ScaleTransform` followed by a `TranslateTransform`, given these transforms:

```
ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
```

The following two options should provide equivalent results:

Using `TransformGroup`:

```
TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();
group.Children.Add(st);
group.Children.Add(tt);
image.RenderTransform = group;
```

Using `MatrixTransform`:

```
MatrixTransform mt = new MatrixTransform
{
    Matrix = new Matrix
    {
        M11 = st.ScaleX,
        M22 = st.ScaleY,
        OffsetX = tt.X,
        OffsetY = tt.Y
    }
};
image.RenderTransform = mt;
```